# Can this WPS be used in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wps

is it possible to integrate the following WPS-LINK in QGIS?
http://gdz.bkg.bund.de/wps_koordtrans?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WPS

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I tried it with the WPS_Client but it didn't work!

Comment: I am able to connect to server but no vector layer..

Answer (score 3):

Yes..Its possible in QGIS.You need to check your network settings & following are the screenshots.

[image: Screen shot 1 -]

[image: Screen shot 2]

Check out [this](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/qgis-with-wps-plugin-in-action/) link included the video (By our Administrator Underdark)..very useful..